# Taking routes from server.js to routes.js without passing parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a `server.js` on my root folder with the following content.

```
// server.js
const app = express();
const HomeController = require("./controllers/HomeController");
const UserController = require("./controllers/UserController");
app.use(...)
app.use(...)

app.get('/', HomeController.index);
app.get('/login', UserController.getLogin);
```

I want to take `app.get` endpoints in a file called routes.js so it looks like this:

```
// routes.js
app.get('/', HomeController.index);
app.get('/login', UserController.getLogin);
```

When I do it, `app`, `HomeController` and `UserController` becomes `undefined`.

I can pass them to routes.js like so:

```
require("routes")(app, HomeController, UserController);
```

However, it is not future compatible so if I ever create a new controller, I must pass them into `routes.js` file.

Instead, can I somehow tell `routes.js` to access `server.js` scope? Is there any way to access variables in `server.js` via `routes.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't use the default pattern of the ExpressJS. like:

```
var apiRoutes = require('./api_server/routes/api');

app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

.../routes/api.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var loginCtrl = require('../controllers/auth/login');

router.post('/authenticate', loginCtrl.login);
router.post('/resetAdminPassword', loginCtrl.resetAdmin);
// router.get('/tieba/:id', tiebaCtrl.one);

module.exports = router;
```